# python keep using same threads in long duration as long running process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, low-latency

I have a model that I want to keep running for over 6 hours paralleled:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
for subModel in self.model:
    pool.apply_async(self.compute, subModel, features)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The problem right now is too slow, as I have to call pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10) and pool.join() each time to construct and deconstruct 10 threads while the model is run tons of times in 6 hours.

The solution I believe is to have 10 threads kept running in the background, so that whenever new data coming in, it will go into model right away not worrying about creating new threads and deconstructing them which wastes a lot of time.

Is there a way in python that allows you to have long running process so that you don't need to start and stop over and over again?

Comment: Are you aware that only 1 python thread can run at a time, making it unsuitable to gain performance?

Comment: I thought multiprocessing.pool, unlike thread class with GIL, can give you multiple threads run at the same time

Comment: @nwp `multiprocessing.Pool` isn't affected by the GIL. Though referring to the pool as having "threads" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `close()` and `join()` (and destroy) the `Pool` after submitting one set of tasks to it. If you want to make sure that your `apply_async()` has completed before going on, just call `apply()` instead, and use the same `Pool` next time. Or, if you can do other stuff while waiting for the tasks, save the result object returned by `apply_async` and call `wait()` on it once you can't go on without it being complete.